# Getting oracle table row lock, from application

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss, transactions

I am getting oracle table row lock, while using below mentioned method written in DAOImpl only in production server. Its working fine in testing server.

```
`public boolean inactiveServices(String custUid) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Long count = (Long) (session.createQuery(
                "select count(*) as intcustomeridpk from CustomerRegistrationPOJO t where t.customerRegistrationPK.custUid = '"
                        + custUid + "'").iterate().next());
        if (count < 1)
            return false;
        String queryToFetchUserIdPk = "select t.customerRegistrationPK.intCustomerId as intcustomeridpk from CustomerRegistrationPOJO t where t.customerRegistrationPK.custUid = '"
                + custUid + "'";
        //Iterator iterator = session.createQuery(queryToFetchUserIdPk).iterate();
        String currentCustIntIdPk = (String) session.createQuery(queryToFetchUserIdPk).iterate().next();
        System.out.println("currentCustIntIdPk  "+currentCustIntIdPk);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CustUtilsPOJO.class).add(
                Restrictions.eq("custUtlilityKey.custUid", currentCustIntIdPk))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("ynActive", "Y"))
                .add(Restrictions.ne("dmlFlag", 2));
        List<CustUtilsPOJO> foundUtilList = criteria.list();
        for (CustUtilsPOJO eachUtil : foundUtilList) {
            System.out.println("centerCode=="+eachUtil.getCenterCode()+"serviceId=="+eachUtil.getCustUtlilityKey().getUtilNumber()+"utilityId=="+eachUtil.getCustUtlilityKey().getUtilId()+"intCustUtil=="+eachUtil.getIntCustomerUtlServiceId());
            eachUtil.setDmlFlag(2);
            eachUtil.setYnActive("N");
            session.merge(eachUtil);
        }
        Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
        txn.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return true;
}`
```

Comment: Is there anything else locking the row? Have you identified what sessions are locking the rows? In order to properly solve this we may need a lot of access to your DB. Maybe you should look at it?

Comment: No only in this case i got row lock.

Comment: DBA have checked database, problem arises while updating particular row. and it occurs occasionally.

Comment: are you selecting across db links by any chance?

Comment: why do you only start the transaction after the merge?

Comment: yeh, you are right, can you please help me to get proper transaction handling in this code???